# Finding End of File in the Redirected Input file in C

Tags: c, io-redirection

I execute my program from shell like that :

```
$main.exe < input.txt
```

in input.txt I have digits (Count of these digits is unknown)

in my program I doing something like :

```
while(1)
{

int xCoordinate, yCoordinate;
scanf("%d %d", &xCoordinate, &yCoordinate);

......

}
```

How can I break this loop when there is no value to read?

Comment: Don't ever use scanf. I tries to do two things (input and parsing) and does neither of them well. If the input began `12xy`, what would the contents of `xCoordinate` be, what would the return value of scanf be and most importanly, what would be the next character read? Use `fgets` and what ever string parsing code you want. You'll always know what is next to be read from stdin, and you can provide better diagnostics than scanf does.

Comment: @msw it is guaranteed that input file consist of only numbers.But thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the input is consistent, you can do it like this:

```
if (scanf("%d %d", &xCoordinate, &yCoordinate) != 2) break;
```

The reason this would work is that `scanf` family of functions return the number of entries that they assigned. In your code, you want `scanf` to assign two items; if EOF is reached instead, a value smaller than 2 would be returned.

**Note:** that this approach will break at the first spot where the input file is not consistent with the format that you expect. For example, if your input has a string in place of one of the numbers, the loop would exit after making a failed attempt to interpret that string as a number.

Comment: Except if there is an input line of `xyz` the `%d` conversion will fail, scanf will return not 2 and the loop will break even if there are thousands of coordinate lines following. This code will break unless the input is *already* checked for consistency, and input is almost never what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the "reading from a file (or stdin)" from the "parsing the line I read. You will get terribly wrong answers if the data is not perfectly what you expect.

You get fine control with something like

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ];
int xCoordinate, yCoordinate;

while(fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL) {
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &xCoordinate, &yCoordinate) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "parsing error\n")
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Even this leaves a bit to be desired because if fgets returns NULL it can either mean EOF or "read error" but it is far more robust than scanf and keeps to the spirit of the original.